# Java Script, PHP - Envia ID de um laço php para uma função JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Galera, eu tenho um botão de deletar que possui um href direcionado para o arquivo de exclusão do php. Eu gostaria de exibir uma mensagem de confirmação antes de enviar o registro para a página de exclusão.
Eu usei o método confirm() do java script para barrar o href do link e deu certo, mas eu queria exibir uma mensagem mais customizada e para tal, usei um framework javaScript chamado sweetAlert. Através da funçâo onclick 
no link, eu chamo a função da mensagem de confirmação, e na funcão, se a opçâo for true, eu envio através do window.location.href para o arquivo php de exclusão. Minha dúvida: Visto que são registros vindo através de um laço while diretamente do banco de dados, como posso enviar o ID do registro 
para a funcao responsavel pela mensagem de confirmaçâo? Visto que o código identificador do registro (pk) está numa váriavel php e a função é js.
Segue o código:

```
//código do link

<a onclick="confirma_excluir_cliente('');" href="exclui_cliente.php?codigo=<?=$linha['codigo']?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

//funcao da mensagem
var confirma_excluir_cliente = function(){

  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
  },
  function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    window.location.href="exclui_cliente.php"
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
  }
});

}
```

desde já, agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta passar o código como parâmetro da função:

```
//código do link (removi as partes desnecessárias pra resposta)

<a href="#" onclick="confirma_excluir_cliente(<?=$linha['codigo']?>);"></a>

//funcao da mensagem
var confirma_excluir_cliente = function(codigo){
    console.log(codigo);
    // continua a função
```

Comment: Ricardo, muito obrigado por responder, deu certo! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o código do PHP na chamada da função no onclick e montar o link dentro da função:

```
<a onclick="confirma_excluir_cliente(<?=$linha['codigo']?>);" href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

//funcao da mensagem
var confirma_excluir_cliente = function(codigo){
    // ...
    window.location.href="exclui_cliente.php?codigo=" + codigo
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Waister, deu certo, muito obrigado pela dica!